# pass multiple parameters with http get request ASP.core API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Dear all i have the following controller,

```
[Route("[action]/{phone}/{password}", Name="PhoneLogin")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PhoneLogin(string phone, string password)
{
    var response = await _repository.PhoneLogin(phone, password);
    if (response == null) { return NotFound(); }
    return Ok(_mapper.Map<UserReadDto>(response));
}

        public async Task<User> PhoneLogin(string phone, string pass)
    {
        StringCipher s = new StringCipher();
        using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spPhoneLogin", sql))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@phone", phone));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", s.EncryptString(pass)));

                User response = null;
                await sql.OpenAsync();

                using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        response = MapToValue(reader);
                    }
                }

                return response;
            }
        }
    }
```

i'm new to API's. i'm trying to send two parameters with the request.
and how is the URI constructed in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your routing attribute `[Route("[action]/{phone}/{password}", Name="PhoneLogin")]`, the method can be reached under */PhoneLogin/anyString/anyOtherString* where *anyString* would be bound to **phone** and *anyOtherString* to **password**.

If you have an additional route attribute on the controller class, such as `[Route("[controller]")]`, the name of your controller also needs to be added which results in */MyControllerName/PhoneLogin/anyString/anyOtherString*.

Please take a closer look at the documentation on [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [routing fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The default model binding follows a predefined order, which (based on the documentation) is

1. Form fields
2. The request body (For controllers that have the [ApiController] attribute.)
3. Route data
4. Query string parameters
5. Uploaded files

So since no form fields or request body is provided (which is the most common case for a get-request), the route data is used to bind the two parameters.

Comment: I know i might sound stupid. I actually posted this here because i was actually doubting my self. My code works fine and the correct too. Turns out i was sending the request to the live version of the API, not the development version. I have been working overtime alot lately haha, I didn't even notice that i was sending the wrong request on postman. Thanks alot for your help and sorry if i wasted your time.